# Simultaneously use wifi and 3G interface on Android?

Tags: android, mobile, wifi, 3g

Is it possible to have both 3G and Wifi connections up and running. I want to transmit at the same time through both interfaces.

However I've noticed that when Wifi is up, 3G is going down. Actually it seems that the routing table is updated on on/off of the interfaces.

1) Route table UMTS on / Wifi onenter code here

```
a.b.c.1 dev rmnet0
a.b.c.0/24 dev rmnet0  src a.b.c.2
default via a.b.c.1 dev rmnet0
```

2) Route table Wifi on / UMTS on

```
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.147
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

3) With wifi on I have run:

```
# ip link set rmnet0 up
# ip route
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.147
a.b.c.0/24 dev rmnet0  src a.b.c.2
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0
```

When I saw that I thought that I have managed to put both device up and running. However this is not the case. When I ping a public internet address (a.b.c.3), in case 1) and 2) everything goes well. In case 3) I get no answer.

Where on earth does Android sets that only one device can be available at a time? How can I make both interfaces to be up and available, like on an ordinary linux box.

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I have tried the solution in [1] to enable the data connection when wifi is on, and no way.

[1] How to enable data connection on Android 2.3

[2] How to block calls in android --> using ITelephony to get the telephonyService.enableDataConnectivity(); but I get an exception.

Answer (score -1):

How is it possible for a device to have multiple IP?

Connecting to 3g will give a new IP which is different from ip given by WIFI.

Comment: Devices have multiple IP addresses all the time. I currently have one from my wired LAN and one from my wireless LAN. I also have virtual networks in VMWare that my computer is concurrently connected to.